# Display values in textbox based dropdown selection jsp

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, servlets

I want to retrieve data from database based on **DropDown Selection**. Following code is working BUT retrieves only one value using selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value But i have three columns in my db table. I want to retrieve all those in text fields based on selection from dropdown.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import = "java.sql.*" %>
    <%@page import = "java.sql.DriverManager.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function populateCustomerId(){
    var selectBox = document.getElementById('selectBox');
     var selectedCustomerId = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('customerId').value = selectedCustomerId;

}</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Select</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
try{   
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ravi","root","root");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = null;
        rs = st.executeQuery("select rid, rname, rmbl from r"); 
%>
    <select id="selectBox" onchange="populateCustomerId();">
        <%while(rs.next()){ %>

            <option value="<%=rs.getString(2) %>"><%=rs.getString(1) %></option>

        <%} %>
        <%}
    catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } %>

    </select>
    <input id="customerId" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="" type="text" value="" />
</td>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you do

```
<select id="selectBox" onchange="populateCustomerId();">
        <%while(rs.next()){ %>

            <option value="<%=rs.getString(2) %>"><%=rs.getString(1) %></option>

        <%} %>
        <%}
    catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } %>

    </select>
```

for every line in the result set (while(rs.next())
you add an option with a value that is a string from the 2nd field in the result set (rs.getString(2))
and the displayed value from the 1st field in the result set (rs.getString(1))

if the display is the issue, than just change the

```
<%=rs.getString(1) %>
```

with

```
rid: <%=rs.getString("rid") %> rname: <%=rs.getString("rname") %> rmbl: <%=rs.getString("rmbl") %>
```

Comment: it is showing all the values in one text box. i need to show each value in different textbox thanku

Comment: it will work when we replace **<%=rs.getString(2)>** with rid: <%=rs.getString("rid") %> rname: <%=rs.getString("rname") %> rmbl: <%=rs.getString("rmbl") %>